# prablem to sync gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I installed **Android Studio 3.4** and I encountered this problem when syncing gradle. I couldn't find a solution to my problem anywhere.

Here's the error I received:

> "Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0 Show in Project Structure
>   dialog Affected Modules: app""
>
> "Failed to resolve:
>   com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3 Show in Project Structure
>   dialog Affected Modules: app""
>
> "Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2 Show in Project Structure
>   dialog Affected Modules: app"
>
> "Failed to resolve:
>   com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2 Show in Project Structure
>   dialog Affected Modules: app"

[image: error log screenshot]

Comment: are you add Google  maven repository on build.gragle project?

Comment: Format error logs in a blockquote instead of formatting it as code. So in the stackoverflow markdown editor, click on **`“`** instead of **`{}`**. I editted this for you.

Comment: I could not understand you

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: @DerkJanSpeelman https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286749/6296561

Comment: @Zoe yeah it does not really matter I suppose https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286752/6086226

Answer (score 2):

```
  repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    }

compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

"Add your gradle file "

Comment: I do not see repositories in my build.gradle file, do I just add "repository" manually I want to include the mavens but I'm not sure where to add them.